# What's the analogue of the display method for UIView?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, nsview

On OSX, if I want to display a `NSView`, I use the method `display`.

What's the analogue for `UIView`?

Comment: The docs on `display` say `Do not call this method directly.` and it is a method on `CALayer` not `NSView`. Can you explain what you're trying to do at a higher level. Maybe then we can help.

Comment: Call [`-setNeedsDisplay`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/setNeedsDisplay) and wait for the next drawing cycle. As far as I know there is no way to update the content of a view immediately.

Comment: @MatthiasBauch I was thinking the same. The exact equivalent would be `drawRect:` or something but you shouldn't be calling that directly. It's a very vague question though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple's documentation is a rather rich source of information - most of the time. The `UIView`class reference notes a method that informs the [system that a view needs to be redrawn](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/setNeedsDisplay): `setNeedDisplay`

Something you should have been aware by browsing the documentation for a couple of seconds.